# Importing and parsing a text file with blanks/NA's into R

Tags: r, parsing, text, import, na

I would like to parse this text file:

https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/saipe/datasets/1995/1995-state-and-county/est95all.dat

The biggest issue, is that the first two lines have information that most lines do not have. Essentially these values should be `NA` in the subsequent columns.

I have been messing around with `library(readr)` a bit and the best easy solution is:

```
DT <- read_table2("https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/saipe/datasets/1995/1995-state-and-county/est95all.dat", 
col_names = FALSE, skip = 2)
```

Which simply skips the first two lines and then parses most lines correctly, leading to:

```
# A tibble: 3,192 x 26
   X1       X2    X3 X4    X5       X6 X7    X8       X9 X10   X11     X12 X13   X14     X15 X16   X17     X18 X19   X20     X21   X22   X23 X24      X25    X26  
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>  <chr>
 1 01        1  5471 4391  6550   13.4 10.8  16.1   2352 1885  2820   20.1 16.1  24.1   1513 1207  1819   17.9 14.3  21.5  34842 31780 37888 Autauga  County AL   
 2 01        3 15494 12415 18573  12.4 9.9   14.9   6151 4886  7416   19.3 15.3  23.3   3927 3098  4756   17.1 13.5  20.7  35014 31981 38031 Baldwin  County AL   
 3 01        5  6423 5153  7692   24.9 20.0  29.8   2564 2049  3078   35.2 28.1  42.2   1716 1366  2066   32.4 25.8  39.1  24423 21343 27485 Barbour  County AL   
 4 01        7  3313 2662  3964   18.1 14.5  21.7   1338 1071  1605   26.2 21.0  31.4    908 722   1094   24.2 19.2  29.1  26651 23548 29737 Bibb     County AL   
 5 01        9  6041 4864  7219   13.7 11.0  16.4   2248 1794  2701   20.6 16.5  24.8   1442 1144  1740   18.4 14.6  22.2  30584 27559 33593 Blount   County AL   
 6 01       11  3524 2817  4231   33.7 26.9  40.5   1448 1149  1746   44.1 35.0  53.2    966 764   1168   41.9 33.1  50.6  19063 15950 22158 Bullock  County AL   
 7 01       13  5540 4436  6644   25.4 20.4  30.5   2347 1865  2828   36.8 29.2  44.3   1576 1244  1908   33.5 26.4  40.5  21918 18822 24998 Butler   County AL   
 8 01       15 20008 16185 23831  17.5 14.2  20.8   7333 5889  8776   25.4 20.4  30.4   4557 3639  5475   21.7 17.3  26.0  27265 24408 30106 Calhoun  County AL   
 9 01       17  6828 5478  8177   18.4 14.7  22.0   2621 2086  3156   27.8 22.1  33.5   1680 1329  2031   24.2 19.2  29.3  25571 22477 28648 Chambers County AL   
10 01       19  3420 2725  4116   15.8 12.6  19.1   1128 893   1363   22.3 17.7  27.0    708 557   859    18.8 14.8  22.8  26719 23647 29775 Cherokee County AL   
# ... with 3,182 more rows
```

This however leads to two issues that I cannot solve.

1. The issue of the first two lines (see link, not data), which is recurring in other lines.
2. The counties often consist of multiple names, spreading the counties over multiple columns

Is there any way to deal with these issues?

The desired result is simply, the data as it is visible in the [link](https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/saipe/datasets/1995/1995-state-and-county/est95all.dat)

Comment: The data you pointed to is not delimited. It's in a fixed-width format. You should be using [read_fwf](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_fwf.html) instead.There is a description of the file format available for that file: https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/saipe/technical-documentation/file-layouts/state-county/1995-estimate-layout.txt

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks! What a dreadful job, but it works..And I guess it is in any case the safest option. Feels like there should somehow be a quicker option though haha.

Comment: @MrFlick I see that the operation removes, decimal points. Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: It shouldn’t. Are you sure you have the field positions correct? Are the values just being rounded during printing? Maybe show the code you are actually running.

Comment: It's a rounding issue, you are right. Sorry. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option scraping the information of the codebook *@MrFlick* found. Examining it, we see that the positions are all in somewhat a `dd- dd  texttext` format. We read it in, using `readLines` and subset it to the lines with those formats. We replace the `"-"` with two spaces using `gsub` and use `strsplit` which gives us three columns each—position start/stop and name.

```
cbl <- "https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/saipe/technical-documentation/file-layouts/state-county/1995-estimate-layout.txt"
cb <- readLines(cbl)
cb <- trimws(gsub("\\t|(?<=\\d)-", "  ", cb[grep("\\t\\d+-", cb)], perl=TRUE))
cb <- strsplit(cb, "\\s{2,}")
```

Now we convert to a matrix and calculate `colDiffs`; adding `2` gives us the desired lengths `w`.

```
w <- matrixStats::colDiffs(type.convert(sapply(cb, `[`, 1:2))) + 2
```

Now we may use `read.fwf` applying `w` and name the variables with the codebook's third column after cleaning it a bit with `make.names`.

```
ll <- "https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/saipe/datasets/1995/1995-state-and-county/est95all.dat"
tt <- setNames(read.fwf(ll, widths=w, header=F), lapply(cb, `[`, 3))
```

#### Result

Here's the result, hope it's all right.

```
head(tt)
# FIPS.State.code FIPS.county.code...0.for.US.or.state.level.records.
# 1               0                                                   0
# 2               1                                                   0
# 3               1                                                   1
# 4               1                                                   3
# 5               1                                                   5
# 6               1                                                   7
# Estimate.of.people.of.all.ages.in.poverty X90..confidence.interval.lower.bound.of
# 1                                  36424609                               35534124 
# 2                                    752097                                 723535 
# 3                                      5471                                   4391 
# 4                                     15494                                  12415 
# 5                                      6423                                   5153 
# 6                                      3313                                   2662 
# X90..confidence.interval.upper.bound.of Estimated.percent.of.people.of.all.ages.in.poverty
# 1                               37315094                                  13.800000000000001
# 2                                 780659                                  17.600000000000001
# 3                                   6550                                  13.400000000000000
# 4                                  18573                                  12.400000000000000
# 5                                   7692                                  24.899999999999999
# 6                                   3964                                  18.100000000000001
# X90..confidence.interval.lower.bound.of X90..confidence.interval.upper.bound.of
# 1                                   13.5                                    14.1 
# 2                                   17.0                                    18.3 
# 3                                   10.8                                    16.1 
# 4                                    9.9                                    14.9 
# 5                                   20.0                                    29.8 
# 6                                   14.5                                    21.7 
# Estimate.of.people.age.0 X90..confidence.interval.lower.bound.of
# 1                 14665019                               14189284 
# 2                   291046                                 275169 
# 3                     2352                                   1885 
# 4                     6151                                   4886 
# 5                     2564                                   2049 
# 6                     1338                                   1071 
# X90..confidence.interval.upper.bound.of Estimated.percent.of.people.age.0
# 1                               15140754                 20.800000000000001
# 2                                 306922                 26.399999999999999
# 3                                   2820                 20.100000000000001
# 4                                   7416                 19.300000000000001
# 5                                   3078                 35.200000000000003
# 6                                   1605                 26.199999999999999
# X90..confidence.interval.lower.bound.of X90..confidence.interval.upper.bound.of
# 1                                   20.1                                    21.5 
# 2                                   25.0                                    27.8 
# 3                                   16.1                                    24.1 
# 4                                   15.3                                    23.3 
# 5                                   28.1                                    42.2 
# 6                                   21.0                                    31.4 
# Estimate.of.related.children.age.5 X90..confidence.interval.lower.bound.of.estimate.of
# 1                            9306018                                            8908791 
# 2                             187857                                             176899 
# 3                               1513                                               1207 
# 4                               3927                                               3098 
# 5                               1716                                               1366 
# 6                                908                                                722 
# X90..confidence.interval.upper.bound.of.estimate.of
# 1                                            9703245 
# 2                                             198815 
# 3                                               1819 
# 4                                               4756 
# 5                                               2066 
# 6                                               1094 
# Estimated.percent.of.related.children.age.5
# 1                          18.699999999999999
# 2                          23.800000000000001
# 3                          17.899999999999999
# 4                          17.100000000000001
# 5                          32.399999999999999
# 6                          24.199999999999999
# X90..confidence.interval.lower.bound.of.estimate.of.percent
# 1                                                       17.9 
# 2                                                       22.4 
# 3                                                       14.3 
# 4                                                       13.5 
# 5                                                       25.8 
# 6                                                       19.2 
# X90..confidence.interval.upper.bound.of.estimate.of.percent
# 1                                                       19.5 
# 2                                                       25.2 
# 3                                                       21.5 
# 4                                                       20.7 
# 5                                                       39.1 
# 6                                                       29.1 
# Estimate.of.median.household.income X90..confidence.interval.lower.bound.of
# 1                               34076                                   33752
# 2                               27357                                   25953
# 3                               34842                                   31780
# 4                               35014                                   31981
# 5                               24423                                   21343
# 6                               26651                                   23548
# X90..confidence.interval.upper.bound.of Estimate.of.people.under.age.5.in.poverty
# 1                                   34400                                   4816366
# 2                                   28761                                     96545
# 3                                   37888                                        NA
# 4                                   38031                                        NA
# 5                                   27485                                        NA
# 6                                   29737                                        NA
# X90..confidence.interval.lower.bound.of X90..confidence.interval.upper.bound.of
# 1                                 4522061                                 5110671
# 2                                   84990                                  108101
# 3                                      NA                                      NA
# 4                                      NA                                      NA
# 5                                      NA                                      NA
# 6                                      NA                                      NA
# Estimated.percent.of.people.under.age.5.in.poverty X90..confidence.interval.lower.bound.of
# 1                                 24.199999999999999                      22.699999999999999
# 2                                 31.600000000000001                      27.800000000000001
# 3                                                 NA                                      NA
# 4                                                 NA                                      NA
# 5                                                 NA                                      NA
# 6                                                 NA                                      NA
# X90..confidence.interval.upper.bound.of                           State.or.county.name
# 1                      25.600000000000001 United States                                 
# 2                      35.399999999999999 Alabama                                       
# 3                                      NA Autauga County                                
# 4                                      NA Baldwin County                                
# 5                                      NA Barbour County                                
# 6                                      NA Bibb County                                   
# Two.letter.Postal.State.abbreviation
# 1                                   US
# 2                                   AL
# 3                                   AL
# 4                                   AL
# 5                                   AL
# 6                                   AL
```

Sure–the column names are far too long and messy, but I leave that one to you ;)

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much! When I run your code, something goes wrong in the last line: `Error in if (header) { : argument is not interpretable as logical` I get a warning as well, but I think that one should not be an issue `In addition: Warning message:
In if (header) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: @Tom Hmm, just reran the code in a fresh session using R 4.0.3 without loading additional packages, and no warnings/errors, works for me!

Comment: Thanks, I just checked. It runs without any libraries loaded in 3.6.1 as well. So I guess I have a library conflict. Thank you so much for your help!